How to implement Robust Adversarial Reinforcement Learning using Stable Baselines 3?
My goal is to implement a custom version of the Robust Adversarial Reinforcement Learning (RARL) algorithm using the the algorithms and functions already provided by Stable Baselines 3 (SB3).
The following is the pseudocode of the algorithm:
RARL pseudocode
The problem I'm having with designing the gym environment and the training method using SB3 is that the training is alternated between the protagonist and the adversary, with only one of them being trained at a time. However, both of them are taking actions using their policies. Hence, I am unsure how to use standard SB3 algorithms with this.
How should I do this? Is the solution to write a custom implementation of SB3 algorithms?
I have tried making different types of environments and experimenting with Petting Zoo. However, I haven't been able to understand what's the best method to go forward with if I want to use existing libraries for RL algorithms and make a multi-agent environment.
